# Not able to assign data from cross domain json to a variable in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am a newbie to Ajax, I am trying to fetch data from using Ajax Cross domain functionality. Ajax function is being called from test.php which calls the stats.php to request data

Stats.php

```
<?php 
   $data = array();
   $data[0]=1;
   $data[1]=1;
   echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Test.php

```
<html>
    <head>
  <script src="./lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var var0=0;
            $(document).ready(setInterval(function() {
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://10.0.0.2/dashBoard/stats.php",
                data: "",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data){
                                       console.log(window.var0 = data[0]);
                                }
                                });
        }, 1000));
            $(document).ready(setInterval(function()
                                         {
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = window.var0;
            },1000));
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="p1"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.php is in 10.0.0.1
stats.php is in 10.0.0.2

Ajax is able to call stats.php and i can see the response json but i am not able to use this response data in test.php. I am not able to assign `data[0]` value which is 1 according to stats.php to `window.var0` in test.php which is a global variable. However this works perfectly fine when stats.php is in 10.0.0.1 along with test.php but my requirement is to load data from stats.php in 10.0.0.2.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error in the javascript console?

Comment: Hi mkaatman, no i am not getting CORS, but however i replaced $.ajax with $.getJSON and it worked without any hiccups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you decoupled the function that brings the data from the server and the function that takes that data and changes the `DOM` based on the server response. Furthermore, you are executing both functions at the same time. This means the function that changes the `DOM` will fire before the response from server comes back.

The main purpose of using an `$ajax` is to know when the response has come back, so you could use that data. By placing `$.ajax` in a function and what you do with the response in another, you break this  "wait for data to come" behavior. The whole purpose of the `success` function is that it executes when the response has returned successfully. In `success` you already have the data. So use it to change `DOM` directly:

Use this instead:

```js
$(document).ready(setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://10.0.0.2/dashBoard/stats.php",
        data: "",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = data[0];
        }
    });
}, 1000));
```

I can't be sure, since I don't know the context, but most likely, you can safely remove the timeout wrapper now. There's no point in delaying the call for data, right?

```js
var var0;

function updateP1(){
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = var0;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://10.0.0.2/dashBoard/stats.php",
        data: "",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonpCallback: 'callback',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            var0 = data[0];
            updateP1();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei, this is a valuable suggestion...but how do i assign the response data to a global variable and use it in some other functions?

Comment: @someshgarje, you can do whatever you want in `success` function of the `$.ajax()` call. Including placing the data in a variable from global scope and calling functions from the same scope. I updated the second example with an example.

Comment: Hello Andrei, thanks a lot for this suggestion this worked